# On-response function only called for last iteration in iron ajax in polymer

Tags: polymer-2.x

In polymer 2.0, I am using iron-ajax to call rest service. I am calling iron-ajax in for loop. I am using loading property of iron-jax to call custom function when loading is done.

The problem is that this custom function is called by application only for last iteration of for loop. It should have been called for each iteration. Can you please guide to get out of this problem?